# Constructor in Class cannot be applied to gives types

Tags: java

I created a program based on the book "Java How to program" by deitel. In chapter 3 "Making a difference" exercise it says:

> (Target-Heart-Rate Calculator) Create a class called HeartRates. The
>   class attributes should include the person’s first name, last name and date of birth (consisting of separate
>   attributes for the month, day and year of birth). Your class should have a constructor that receives
>   this data as parameters. For each attribute provide set and get methods. The class also should
>   include a method that calculates and returns the person’s age (in years), a method that calculates and
>   returns the person’s maximum heart rate and a method that calculates and returns the person’s target
>   heart rate. Write a Java application that prompts for the person’s information, instantiates an object
>   of class HeartRates and prints the information from that object—including the person’s first name,
>   last name and date of birth—then calculates and prints the person’s age in (years), maximum heart
>   rate and target-heart-rate range.

So I wrote this code:

```
// File: HeartRates.java

public class HeartRates {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    // constructor
    public HeartRates( String fName, String lName, int aMonth,
        int aDay, int aYear) {

        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        month = aMonth;
        day = aDay;
        year = aYear;
    }

    // method to set first name
    public void setFirstName( String fName ) {
        firstName = fName;
    }

    // method to get first name
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    } 

    // method to set last name
    public void setLastName( String lName ) {
        lastName = lName;
    }

    // method to get last name
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    // method to set month
    public void setMonth( int aMonth ) {
        month = aMonth;
    }

    // method to get month
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    // method to set day
    public void setDay( int aDay ) {
        day = aDay;
    }

    // method to get day
    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    // method to set year
    public void setYear( int aYear ) {
        year = aYear;
    }

    // method to get year
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    // returns person's age
    public int ageInYears() {
        return 2018 - getYear();
    }

    // returns maximum heart rate
    public int maxHeartRate() {
        return 220 - ageInYears();
    } 

    // display target heart rate
    public String targetHeartRate() {
    // targetHeartRate = range 50% - 85% of maxheartrate
        double fifty = 0.5 * maxHeartRate();
        double eightyFive = 0.85 * maxHeartRate();
        String target = (int)fifty + " BPM - " + (int)eightyFive + " BPM\n"; 
        return target;
    }

} // end class HeartRates
```

and another class to test it:

```
// File: HeartRatesTest.java
// Testing heart rate class
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeartRatesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        HeartRates profile = new HeartRates();

        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;

        // collecting user's information
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        firstName = input.nextLine();
        profile.setFirstName( firstName );

        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        lastName = input.nextLine();
        profile.setLastName( lastName );

        System.out.print("Enter your date of birth(month day year): ");
        month = input.nextInt();
        profile.setMonth( month );
        day = input.nextInt();
        profile.setDay( day );
        year = input.nextInt();
        profile.setYear( year );

        // displaying user's information
        System.out.printf( "\nFirst Name: %s\n", profile.getFirstName() );
        System.out.printf( "Last Name: %s\n", profile.getLastName() );
        System.out.printf( "Date of birth: %d\\%d\\%d\n", 
            profile.getMonth(), profile.getDay(), profile.getYear() );
        System.out.printf( "Age: %d\n", profile.ageInYears() );
        System.out.printf( "Maximum heart rate: %d BPM\n", profile.maxHeartRate() );
        System.out.printf( "Target heart rate: " + profile.targetHeartRate() );

    } // end method main
} // end class HeartRateTest
```

but I get this error message:

```
 HeartRatesTest.java:10: error: constructor HeartRates in class
 HeartRates cannot be applied to given types;
                 HeartRates profile = new HeartRates();
                                      ^   required: String,String,int,int,int   
 found: no arguments   reason: actual and
 formal argument lists differ in length 1 error
```

But I don't know why is asking me to put String,String,int,int,int.
Can anyone help me fix this error?

Comment: Your constructor is `public HeartRates( String fName, String lName, int aMonth,
 int aDay, int aYear) { ... }`, so it requires two strings and three ints.  It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Add an empty no-args `public` constructor to `HeartRates`. Because you have provided **a** constructor, you don't get the default constructor anymore. **Or**, follow the instructions you have and call the constructor you have implemented.

Comment: Why did I get -4 vote?

Comment: @Nassir maybe because of the descriptive content in the question body...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor     `public HeartRates( String fName, String lName, int aMonth, int aDay, int aYear)`  of class `HeartRates` has the arguments `String,String,int,int,int`.

So you have to provide those values in

```
HeartRates profile = new HeartRates(); // need values as argument
```

Some thing like:-

```
// calling constructor with arguments
HeartRates profile = new HeartRates(firstName, lastName, month, day, year);
```

Modified `HeartRatesTest.java`

```
// File: HeartRatesTest.java
// Testing heart rate class
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeartRatesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;

        // collecting user's information
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        firstName = input.nextLine(); // no need of setFirstName()

        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        lastName = input.nextLine(); // no need of setLastName()

        System.out.print("Enter your date of birth(month day year): ");
        month = input.nextInt(); // no need of setMonth()
        day = input.nextInt();   // no need of setDay()
        year = input.nextInt();  // no need of setYear()

        /* Object of HeartRates is defined after reading all values */
        HeartRates profile = new HeartRates(firstName, lastName, month, day, year); // calling constructor with arguments

        // displaying user's information
        System.out.printf("\nFirst Name: %s\n", profile.getFirstName());
        System.out.printf("Last Name: %s\n", profile.getLastName());
        System.out.printf("Date of birth: %d\\%d\\%d\n", profile.getMonth(), profile.getDay(), profile.getYear());
        System.out.printf("Age: %d\n", profile.ageInYears());
        System.out.printf("Maximum heart rate: %d BPM\n", profile.maxHeartRate());
        System.out.printf("Target heart rate: " + profile.targetHeartRate());

    } // end method main
} // end class HeartRateTest
```

when you use constructor properly you don't need to use those `set-functions`. Every data insertions can be done by your constructor.

**Output :-**

```
Enter your first name: abc
Enter your last name: def
Enter your date of birth(month day year): 12 25 1998

First Name: abc
Last Name: def
Date of birth: 12\25\1998
Age: 20
Maximum heart rate: 200 BPM
Target heart rate: 100 BPM - 170 BPM
```